# Simple Circuit: light source seperated from signal source?

Tags: circuit-design, circuits

Forgive me for the simple question!

- How would I create a circuit for a light that is switched on when another light is switched on?
- Basically I want to use a more powerful source for a new light that is  activated by another light with a smaller source. Something simple that I might be able to solder up.

I'm making a pinball game light modification and I want to grab the signal off of one of the interactive lights, but a more powerful source for a bigger light.

Comment: Get a DMM and measure the voltage

Comment: You can do this yes, probably with a photoresistor to detect light, a transistor to switch the light on and off based on the current through the photoresistor, and some resistors to tweak things.

Comment: @immibis I'm looking into a voltage controlled switch possibly? If I have access to the voltage powering the "signal" light - is there some way I could have the mod light circuit shorted until current comes through the signal wire?

Comment: yes, you can feed the signal to a logic-level mosfet to turn it on and thus use it as a low-side switch. It won't draw much of anything away from the light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up using a N24401 transistor as a switch. Here is the schematic of the circuit that I used!

[image]